# Validacao no construtor - Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, validação

Fiz essa classe entretanto, quando entro com valores que em teoria não deveriam ser permitidos ela continua executando normalmente, mesmo tendo criado uma função que faz a validação.

Não consigo chama-la dentro do construtor.

Como valido esses dados ou chamo a função antes que os métodos que eu chamo pelos objetos sejam executados.

```
class Data():

def __init__(self, dia = 1, mes = 1, ano = 1980):
    self.__dia = dia
    self.__mes = mes
    self.__ano = ano

def eAnterior(self, dataComp):
    if dataComp.getAno() > self.getAno():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() > self.getMes():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() == self.getMes() and dataComp.getDia() >= self.getDia():
        return False
    else:
        return True

def ePosterior(self, dataComp):
    if dataComp.getAno() < self.getAno():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() < self.getMes():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() == self.getMes() and dataComp.getDia() <= self.getDia():
        return False
    else:
        return True

def eSimultaneo(self, dataComp):
    if dataComp.getAno() != self.getAno():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() != self.getMes():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() == self.getMes() and dataComp.getDia() != self.getDia():
        return False
    else:
        return True    

def _valida(self, dia = 0, mes = 0, ano = 0):
    if dia < 1 or dia > 31:
        return False
    elif mes < 1 or mes > 12:
        return False
    elif ano < 1: 
        return False
    return True

def setData(self, dia, mes, ano):
    if self._valida(dia, mes, ano):
        self.setDia(dia)
        self.setMes(mes)
        self.setAno(ano)
    else:
        self.setDia(1)
        self.setMes(1)
        self.setAno(1980)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.getDia()}/{self.getMes()}/{self.getAno()}'

def getDia(self):
    return self.__dia

def setDia(self, dia):
    self.__dia = dia

def getMes(self):
    return self.__mes

def setMes(self, mes):
    self.__mes = mes

def getAno(self):
    return self.__ano

def setAno(self, ano):
    self.__ano = ano

if __name__ == '__main__':
data = Data('a', 'b', 'c')
print(data)
data2 = Data(27, 9, 1998)
data3 = Data(27, 9, 2015)
if data.eSimultaneo(data3):
    print('iguais')
else:
    print('diferentes')
```

Comment: No Python não utilizamos getters e setters. Se precisamos aplicar uma regra de negócio nestas operações utilizamos a propriedade (`@property`). Conhece?

Comment: Conheço, mas ainda não consegui utilizar da forma correta. Ou seja, não sei utilizar =/

Comment: Existe um motivo pra criar uma classe e não usar o `datetime.date`?

Comment: sim, fins acadêmicos. @PedrovonHertwig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o método de validação dentro de `__init__`, por exemplo:

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self, dia = 1, mes = 1, ano = 1980):
        self.__dia = dia 
        self.__mes = mes 
        self.__ano = ano
        if not self._valida():
            raise ValueError("valores inválidos")
```

Também seria mais Pythônico usar os atributos da instância no método `_valida`, ao invés de passar argumentos cujo valor a instância já possui:

```
def _valida(self): 
    if not 1 <= self.__dia <= 31:
        return False 
    if not 1 <= self.__mes <= 12:
        return False 
    if self.__ano < 1: 
        return False
    return True
```

Uma outra dica: como comentado, em Python não se usa getters e setters, mas o decorador `@property`, por exemplo:

```
@property  # equivale ao getter
def dia(self):
    return self.__dia

@dia.setter  # equivale ao setter
def dia(self, dia):
    self.__dia = dia
    self._valida()  # validando valores novamente
```

Isso dá suporte à sintaxe Pythônica de usar `minha_instancia.dia` como getter e `minha_instancia.dia = novo_dia` como setter.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Esclareceu muitas dúvidas.

Comment: Utilizando o decorador @property, é melhor utilizar atributo "__privado" ou "_protegido" ? Existe uma convenção quanto a isso?

Comment: Como você já deve saber, em Python todos os atributos e métodos de uma classe são públicos - usar _ para protegidos e __ para privados é apenas convenções que sugerem a quem ler o código que certo atributo não deve ser acessado diretamente. No seu caso, acredito que o uso mais adequado é proteger os atributos `dia`, `mes` e `ano`, já que você interage com eles indiretamente através do `@property`. Mas em última análise é uma questão estilística.

Comment: Amigo, quando você chama o valida() no @dia.setter, ele vai retornar falso, sem uma condicional como ele vai verificar isso e impedir a entrada desse valor no atributo?

Comment: Você está certo, idealmente você teria de pegar o valor falso e fazer algo com ele (como erguer um erro, como fiz no método init). Não me preocupei muito com a lógica do seu programa em si, o código foi mais uma demonstração de como é possível fazer uma função arbitrária ser executada quando alguém redefine um atributo como a sintaxe `minha_instancia.attr = valor`.